# Bootstrap navbar behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ive been trying to use bootstrap's navbar but it seems that its doing something wrong, the navbar looks like this (even on a wide screen)

[image: Navbar]

the code is the following

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Gerencial</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xs sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                       data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</div>

<p>Test page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Fun thing is im using the exact same sample code on bootstrap docs and it should look like this

[image: Proper navbar]

I did change the color and the text to the right but other than that, everything is preety much the same, any suggestions on what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `navbar-expand-sm` class (or -md or -lg, depending of which breakpoint you want to target)

**Bootply**: https://www.bootply.com/RVELYbOueA

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xs navbar-expand-sm sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Would you know why they didnt bother mentioning such a relevant fact on the docs? Also, the example they use on the sample page does not use this class and still looks different, mind telling me why?

Comment: In fact, it's clearly written in the doc : look at here, first entry : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works